# Android SharedPreferences using tab activity

Tags: android

I have two tabs(fragments) and one main activity. In fragment 2, I want to use `SharedPerferences` to store a value and check if the previous one is larger or not. If it is, then replace it with a higher value. Fragment 1 is used to display the value only. After opening the app, fragment 1 is the default fragment.

In Fragment 2:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

int score = sharedPref.getInt("marks", 0);

if (newS > score) { //newS is the new score
  editor.putInt("marks", newS);
  editor.commit();
}
```

In fragment 1:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int score = sharedPref.getInt("marks", 0);
x.setText(score); //x is a text view.
```

But when I run it, the app keeps closing.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3495)
      at com.example.mygames.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:31)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1979)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteIni
03-04 22:22:18.782 310-943/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.mygames/.MainActivity
```

Comment: You should show your log

Comment: how can I show it?

Comment: In android studio look for Android Monitor then in logcat copy/paste logs show when the app crash .

Comment: I have update with the log.

Comment: Have you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to set text with a int : `x.setText(score)` but score is not matching with a id of string ressources.

If you want to show the score value to the textview you can do : `x.setText(String.valueOf(score));`